# How does refcell interact with the borrow checker

Tags: rust, reference, borrow-checker

I am trying to wrap my head around the RefCell type, not as a utility, but in terms of it's implementation.

I understand the general idea, a struct that has mutable data inside of it that keeps track of how many active references to that data exist.

but how does it interact with the borrow checker to allow you to mutate the data multiple times?

Comment: Look up [UnsafeCell](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html)

Comment: Jon Gjensgset made a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8O0Nt9qY_vo) implementing them by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but how does it interact with the borrow checker to allow you to mutate the data multiple times?

Internally, it doesn't really - it uses unsafe code.

`RefCell` is a checked wrapper around `UnsafeCell`, which provides the inner mutability. Its `get` method returns a `*mut` pointer to the wrapped type, which can be cast to a `&mut` reference with an arbitrary lifetime. This, of course, is very unsafe, so **it's up to the user to ensure there's no violations of the borrow checker rules with `UnsafeCell`.**

`Cell` does this by not allowing references to the inner object. `RefCell` does this via essentially a single-threaded lock, keeping track of whether a reference exists and denying access if so. `Mutex` and `RwLock` are similar, but use thread-safe locks.

(As an aside, `UnsafeCell` IS compiler magic, but for a different reason - it's needed to tell the compiler that an object may change behind an immutable reference. But that doesn't have to do with the borrow checks so much as optimizations.)